# Relative path to executable is not resolved in zsh script

Tags: unix, zsh

I have a personal scripts folder: `~/google_drive/code/scripts`.  This folder is on my $path.  $path is set in `~/.zshenv` and not changed anywhere else (I've disabled OS X path_helper and I don't touch $path in any other zsh startup file).  In this scripts folder, there is a subdirectory called `alfred_workflows`.  From the command line, from any location I am able to run scripts in this folder with relative paths.  This is expected:

```
$ alfred_workflows/test.sh
#=> test successful
```

But in a script, this does not work.  It generates an error:

```
$ zsh -c "alfred_workflows/test.sh"
#=> zsh:1: no such file or directory: alfred_workflows/test.sh
```

Once again, the `scripts` directory that contains `alfred_workflows` is on `$path`, which is set in `~/.zshenv`, and I am able to run executables that reside in the top level of this directory from a script.  The issue only seems to be when I try to go through a subdirectory.  What might be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Searching of the `$path` is only done for names containing a slash if the 
[path_dirs](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-PATH_005fDIRS) option is set.  Apparently that's set in your interactive shell, 
but isn't set in the process that's executing the script.

Comment: Brilliant!  This was driving me nuts.  Thanks so much.